# Help – keep garage dry and well-ventilated (dryer exhaust hose)

Tags: garage, dryer, ventilation, humidity

I just got an old car and need to keep my garage dry and well-ventilated.

Right now my biggest problem is that I have about 3 feet of 4-inch dryer exhaust hose going from my laundry room to a hole that feeds the exhaust right into the garage.  It blows a lot of warm and humid air into the garage.

1. Should I do the work to redirect this hose to the outdoors?
2. Can I avoid that by getting another length of hose, connecting it to the exhaust hole, and letting the output end sit under the garage door?
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: If by well ventilated you have lots of air coming in and going out, then maybe nothing needs to change.  Adding extra pipe/hose and venting dryer outside is cheap also, as long as you don't need excessive length, around 10 or 15 feet be okay if only using 3 feet now.  Check for change in dryer times.

Answer (score 3):

My neighbor had a handy man run about 20 feet of 4" PVC sch 40 pipe and 3 elbows through his garage and exit through the wall. The dryer runs fine with no change in the dryers performance.

Comment: That will be fun in a lint fire. Not that many other commonly used dryer vents (the accordion hose junk, foil or not) won't also be. I stick to solid metal for dryer ducts.